# R connect string and dynamic variables

Tags: r

some other languages have this:

```
i=1
x&i=3
```

Then you will get a variable `x1=3`

**How to realize this in R?**

please don't use `assign(paste0('x',1),3)`.
Because I want to iterate i, for example:

```
x1=c()
for(i in 1:100){
x1=c(x1,2*i)}
```

And I want x1,x2...xn. `assign(paste)` only generates variables once and doesn't have adding functions.

So the grammar `x&i` is the core problem.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It would be common to use some data structure that natively supports indexing to hold these variables.

Comment: It's also not clear what output you desire.

Comment: By 'add' I mean add elements to the variables x1 instead of adding a number 1.

Comment: For example, x1=c(2,45,13,65),x2=c(45,2,55,77,2)...xn, assign can't append elements. It just generate a variable once and then do nothing. The core problem is how to realize x&i. Because the & in R is a logical computation sign instead of connect sign. That what I am asking!

Comment: I still cannot understand your question but `assign` can append element like this `x1 <- 1 ; assign("x2", c(x1, 3))`, of course in for loop.

Comment: I'm curious as to why not you are not using an indexed vector instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
e <- .GlobalEnv
i <- 1
xi.name <- paste0("x", i)

# assign
e[[xi.name]] <- 3

# add
e[[xi.name]] <- e[[xi.name]] + 1

# display
e[[xi.name]]
## [1] 4
```

or using `assign` and `get` the above could be done like this:

```
i <- 1
xi.name <- paste0("x", i)

# assign
assign(xi.name, 3)

# add
assign(xi.name, get(xi.name) + 1)

# display
get(xi.name)
## [1] 4
```

Note that normally one does not generate dynamic variables but rather puts them into a list.

```
L <- list()
i <- 1
xi.name <- paste0("x", i)

# assign
L[[xi.name]] <- 3

# add
L[[xi.name]] <- L[[xi.name]] + 1

# display
L[[xi.name]]
## [1] 4
```

or simply:

```
L <- list()
i <- 1

# assign
L[[i]] <- 3

# add
L[[i]] <- L[[i]] + 1

# display
L[[i]]
## [1] 4
```

### Note

```
e <- .GlobalEnv
i <- 1
xi.name <- paste0("x", i)
x1 <- 3

e[[xi.name]] <- c(e[[xi.name]], 99)
x1
## [1] 3 99

e <- .GlobalEnv
i <- 1
xi.name <- paste0("x", i)
x1 <- 3
assign(xi.name, c(get(xi.name), 99))
x1
## [1] 3 99
```

Comment: Sorry I did not state it clearly. What I want is to add an element in the variable x1, rather than add 1.

Comment: `e[[xi.name]] <- c(e[[xi.name]], 99)`  or `assign(xi.name, c(get(xi.name), 99))`

Comment: `assign(xi.name, c(get(xi.name), 99))` doesn't work but the `e[[xi.name]] <- c(e[[xi.name]], 99)` is actually what I want. Thanks so much and...Happy new year!!!

Comment: It works for me. See Note I have added where it gives the same result as using `e[[...]]`